# base64 HmacSHA1 decode in iPhone

Tags: iphone, base64, hmacsha1

I am working on an iPhone application that requires `Base64` decoding using `HmacSHA1` algorithm. Can anyone help me doing the objective-C equivalent of the given Java code:

```
SecretKeykey = new SecretKeySpec(com.sinotar.algorithm.Base64.decode(
    "vNQKX3C1wD/KprnnOcdRwM80YIn5bo47w9VdTlDpCB8="), "HmacSHA1");
```

---

Thanks matthijz, But it has nothing to do with HmacSHA1. The solution I am looking for is something that does the equivalent of the Java code:

```
SecretKey key = null; 
try { key = new SecretKeySpec(com.sinotar.algorithm.Base64.decode("vNQKX3C1wD/KprnnOcdRwM80YIn5bo47w9VdTlDpCB8="), 
                              "HmacSHA1"); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to base64 decode then HMACSHA1 the result?

Comment: What is the `com.sinotar` package? It's not part of the standard Java library. What does it do? Just Base64 encoding/decoding?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Matt Gallagher's article on Base64 encoding - it has downloadable code at the end. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: Thanks matthijz, But it has nothing to do with HmacSHA1. The solution I am looking for is something that does the equivalent of the Java code:

SecretKey key = null; try { key = new SecretKeySpec(com.sinotar.algorithm.Base64.decode("vNQKX3C1wD/KprnnOcdRwM80YIn5bo47w9VdTlDpCB8="), "HmacSHA1"); }

Answer (score 0):

The code you quote appears to be taking a base64 value, converting it to binary, and using it to set the key for an HMACSHA1 algorithm.  The two steps are conceptually separate.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Digest__HMAC_SHA1.3pm.html) is the page for HMAC_SHA1 on Mac -- I haven't found the equivalent for iPhone, but I would assume it exists.